# Stereoeffect.js is not working. It shows black screen

Tags: three.js

I want to switch `steroeffect` view on click of button. But when i click and enable stereo effect. Scene is blank and shows black screen.

I tried adding this to renderer still no luck.

```
    const size = this.renderer.getSize();
    this.renderer.setScissor( 0, 0, size.width, size.height );
    this.renderer.setViewport( 0, 0, size.width, size.height );
```

```
this.effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

resizeHandler(event) {
 this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);     
 this.effect.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

enableVrMode() {
    this.stereoEffect = !this.stereoEffect;
    this.resizeHandler(true);
    this.render();
}

render() {
    if (this.renderer) {
      if (this.stereoEffect) {
        this.effect.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      } else {
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
      }
    }
}
```

Whole scene shows black screen. Kindly guide me to fix this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a live example?

Comment: Hello Mugen87. Actually the thing is i am currently using threejs in angular project so i want button that enables or disables stereoeffect.
This is my code initialization.

this.effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(this.renderer);
this.effect.eyeSeparation = 5;
this.effect.setSize( this.canvasConfig.CANVAS_WIDTH, this.canvasConfig.CANVAS_HEIGHT );
```